# Converting A List of MediaItem to ConcatenatingAudioSource Error: Instance of 'ConcatenatingAudioSource'

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am trying to parse/convert a list of `MediaItem` to a `ConcatenatingAudioSource`, but my unit test keeps giving me an error that the converted `ConcatenatingAudioSource` does not match up with the target source. My test is

```
List<MediaItem> audioSource = <MediaItem>[
      MediaItem(
        // This can be any unique id, but we use the audio URL for convenience.
        id: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3",
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5739820),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
      ),
      MediaItem(
        id: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3",
        album: "Science Friday",
        title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
        artist: "Science Friday and WNYC Studios",
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2856950),
        artUri: Uri.parse(
            "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg"),
      ),
];

test('mediaItem2ConcatenatingAudioSource test', () {
      expect(
        // Here's where the conversion happens
        ConcatenatingAudioSource(
          children: audioSource
              .map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id)))
              .toList(),
        ),
        ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
          AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
              'https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3')),
          AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(
              "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3")),
        ]),
      );
});
```

The error I get is below. I believe it is saying that the two `ConcatenatingAudioSource` are not the same, where they should be.

```
Expected: <Instance of 'ConcatenatingAudioSource'>
  Actual: <Instance of 'ConcatenatingAudioSource'>
```

I literally copied the conversion part from the `audio_service` example (line 362), so I'm really confused about what is wrong here. (This conversion code also doesn't work when my actual app is running. I put the `actual` part of the test in a `setSource()` method then `play()`, but nothing happens.)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just_audio does not consider two audio sources to be equal even if they contain the same metadata. This is because each copy has its own internal buffer and different internal state.

All you can do is check the equality of the metadata within the audio sources. For example to compare the playlists `a` and `b`:

```dart
ConcatenatingAudioSource a = ...;
ConcatenatingAudioSource b = ...;

expect(
  a.children.map((s) => (s as UriAudioSource).uri).toList(),
  b.children.map((s) => (s as UriAudioSource).uri).toList(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Just about to delete that unit test (just kidding lol).